# PowerBuilder Datawindow Expression Changes Not Reflected until reopen of object

Tags: powerbuilder

How do you force PowerBuilder to reflect recent changes to properties of a datawindow object while making changes in the datawindow painter? For example, I'm setting background color of a column based on an expression and I retrieve the data in development mode to do quick test but each time I change the RGB color for background it isn't reflected in datawindow unless I close and reopen it- then re-retrieve some data. Annoying and it happens with other properties, display formats, etc.

Adding detail to this question:

- The column is a computed field in a grid style datawindow having a number in it representing the remaining volume (available minus used) percentage.
- Column has display format of 0.00%
- Background Color set to white with expression code
- Background Color expression code is below

**The problem:** Let's say I'm not sure what the percentages or colors are- and I'm changing them while developing. Any change to the expression is not reflected in background color unless datawindow closed and reopened- and re-retrieved of course.

```
if ( 
     ( 
       (epa_approved_volume -  
         if (isnull(epa_used_volume) ,0 ,epa_used_volume)
       ) / epa_approved_volume) < 0.01, rgb(240, 40, 40), 
  if (
       ( 
         (epa_approved_volume -  
          if ( isnull(epa_used_volume ) , 0 , epa_used_volume )
         ) / epa_approved_volume) < 0.25, rgb(250, 250, 0), rgb(50, 200, 50) 
     )
   )
```

Comment: Can you give us an example where this does not work?

Comment: @imankurpatel000 Absolutely- I'm going to insert it at the end of the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been an issue for many versions. I would submit it as a bug. Appeon is much more open to fixing bugs th SAP or Sybase ever were.

Comment: I had a hunch it was a PowerBuilder bug, hoped someone knew of a solution though. I agree about Appeon- they are the best thing that could have happened to PowerBuilder, and their new licensing model makes it affordable too. Thanks Roland.